# Is it possible to have a complete parallel plan for a query which includes window functions using order clauses (e.g. cumulative sum with order by)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, parallel-processing, postgresql-12

So, I have a query which starts off with joining one large table (5Mio records) with several others. This part of the query parallellises perfectly by specifying this first:

```
set max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 12;
set parallel_setup_cost = 0;--1000
set parallel_tuple_cost = 0;
set max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 4;
set min_parallel_table_scan_size to '1kB';
```

This is the query:

```
explain analyze 
with subca as
(
(with z as (
select 12 as se_id,405 as pe_id,dt.zo_id,dt.co_id,sh.sh_id, n.ct_id
,cast(coalesce(com.value_num,1) * rere.value_num * n.csv * cast(case when shop_concept =2 and n.ct_id = 1 then (0.01) * (greatest(1+ (pn_cvp_public_transport/1400000)+ ln(least(greatest(activity_map_fte,4000),150000)/60000)/7
,0.1)) * (1/exp(dt*ddp)) when shop_concept =1 and n.ct_id = 1 then (0.01) * (greatest(1
+(total_openinghours-35)*0.018
+ (atm-2)*0.05
+  0.15*(last_significant_works-2)
- (open_saturday-1)*0.05
+ ln(least(greatest(activity_map_fte,25000),150000)/60000)/7
 + case centrally_located_avg when 1 then -0.1 when 3 then 0.06 else 0.0 end
+(greatest(nps,30)-60)/600
+case when parking = 1 then 0.03 else 0 end
+ case passage_foot when 1 then -0.05 when 4 then 0.03 when 5 then 0.06 else 0.0 end
+case when nr_fte < 2.5 then -0.12 else 0.0 end
+case when nr_fte >= 4.5 then 0.15 else 0.0 end
+case when pn_cvp_services = 0 then -0.05 when pn_cvp_services > 15 then 0.05 else 0 end 
+ pn_cvp_non_fashion/40000
,0.01)) * (1/((greatest(least(rev_wealthy,1.8),0.6)^1.5)*exp((dt*ddp+0.35)+0.1))) end as double precision) as float) as attraction
,cast(coalesce(com.value_num,1) * rere.value_num * n.csv * cast(case when shop_concept =2 and n.ct_id = 1 then (0.01) * (greatest(1+ (pn_cvp_public_transport/1400000)+ ln(least(greatest(activity_map_fte,4000),150000)/60000)/7
,0.1)) * (0.01/exp(dt*nddp)) when shop_concept =1 and n.ct_id = 1 then (0.01) * (greatest(1
+(total_openinghours-35)*0.018
+ (atm-2)*0.05
+  0.15*(last_significant_works-2)
- (open_saturday-1)*0.05
+ ln(least(greatest(activity_map_fte,25000),150000)/60000)/7
 + case centrally_located_avg when 1 then -0.1 when 3 then 0.06 else 0.0 end
+(greatest(nps,30)-60)/600
+case when parking = 1 then 0.03 else 0 end
+ case passage_foot when 1 then -0.05 when 4 then 0.03 when 5 then 0.06 else 0.0 end
+case when nr_fte < 2.5 then -0.12 else 0.0 end
+case when nr_fte >= 4.5 then 0.15 else 0.0 end
+case when pn_cvp_services = 0 then -0.05 when pn_cvp_services > 15 then 0.05 else 0 end 
+ pn_cvp_non_fashion/40000
,0.01)) * ((0.03+((urbanization_v2-2200)/1000000)-if(urbanization_v2<1000,urbanization_v2/50000,0)
)
/((greatest(least(rev_wealthy,1.5),0.7)^1.5)*exp(dt*nddp))) end as double precision) as float)  as nd_attraction 
, n.fc
from (select pe_id,zo_id,co_id,value_num as dt 
from rtpezocoav x --use view??
where pe_id = 405 and ad_id = 4
) dt
join calc_nodes n on n.co_id = dt.co_id and n.pe_id = 405  and n.se_id = 12
join calc_zones z on dt.zo_id = z.zo_id and z.pe_id = 405 and z.se_id = 12
--!!
left join calc_shopconcepts sh on sh.pe_id = 405 and sh.se_id = 12  and sh.sh_id = n.shop_concept and sh.ct_id = n.ct_id
left join rtsepezobrav com on com.se_id = 12 and com.pe_id =  405 and com.zo_id = z.zo_id and com.br_id = n.br_id and com.ad_id = 308  
join rtseperereav rere on rere.se_id = 12 and rere.pe_id =  405 and rere.re_id = z.re_id and rere.re2_id = n.re_id and rere.ad_id = 306 
)
select se_id,pe_id,zo_id,co_id,sh_id, ct_id, attraction::float, nd_attraction::float, fc from z)
)
, alloc as 
(

        select
          ca.co_id as nodeid, ca.zo_id as zoneid, ic.br_id as ownerid, ic.br2_id as to_owner, 
            (ca.attraction*ca.fc) as attraction, (ca.nd_attraction*ca.fc) as nd_attraction, 
            ca.sh_id as shopconcept, ca.ct_id, ic.value_num as value,
          least(sum(ic.value_num) over w, 30) as r      -- Calculate rank within zone for a given owner (avoid overflow)
          -- Get attractions a(z, n)
        from subca ca  --modify for simulations
        join rtco co on co.lo_id = ca.co_id
        join rvsepebrbrav ic on ic.se_id = 12 and ic.pe_id = 405 and co.br_id = ic.br_id and ic.ad_id = 307 --modify se/pe
        window
         w as (partition by ca.zo_id, ic.br2_id order by ca.attraction desc)
)
select sum(r) from alloc;
```

If I do `select count(1) from alloc` or `select sum(attraction) from alloc`, the query is run completely in parallel. The problem starts when I include the window function as shown above. Then the plan shows the joins being done in parallel, followed by a gather step, and then one large sort which makes the query quite slow:

```
Aggregate  (cost=981588.52..981588.53 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=5844.082..5844.083 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=859448.88..937967.22 rows=3489704 width=64) (actual time=3112.764..5653.421 rows=5019003 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=859448.88..868173.14 rows=3489704 width=20) (actual time=3112.751..3773.671 rows=5019003 loops=1)
               Sort Key: x.zo_id, ((((COALESCE(com.value_num, '1'::double precision) * rere.value_num) * n.csv) * CASE WHEN ((n.shop_concept = '2'::double precision) AND (n.ct_id = 1)) THEN (('0.01'::double precision * G
REATEST((('1'::double precision + (n.pn_cvp_public_transport / '1400000'::double precision)) + (ln((LEAST(GREATEST(n.activity_map_fte, '4000'::double precision), '150000'::double precision) / '60000'::double precision)) 
/ '7'::double precision)), '0.1'::double precision)) * ('1'::double precision / exp((x.value_num * sh.ddp)))) WHEN ((n.shop_concept = '1'::double precision) AND (n.ct_id = 1)) THEN (('0.01'::double precision * GREATEST((
(((((((((((('1'::double precision + ((n.total_openinghours - '35'::double precision) * '0.018'::double precision)) + ((n.atm - '2'::double precision) * '0.05'::double precision)) + ('0.15'::double precision * (n.last_sig
nificant_works - '2'::double precision))) - ((n.open_saturday - '1'::double precision) * '0.05'::double precision)) + (ln((LEAST(GREATEST(n.activity_map_fte, '25000'::double precision), '150000'::double precision) / '600
00'::double precision)) / '7'::double precision)) + (CASE n.centrally_located_avg WHEN '1'::double precision THEN '-0.1'::numeric WHEN '3'::double precision THEN 0.06 ELSE 0.0 END)::double precision) + ((GREATEST(n.nps, 
'30'::double precision) - '60'::double precision) / '600'::double precision)) + (CASE WHEN (n.parking = '1'::double precision) THEN 0.03 ELSE '0'::numeric END)::double precision) + (CASE n.passage_foot WHEN '1'::double p
recision THEN '-0.05'::numeric WHEN '4'::double precision THEN 0.03 WHEN '5'::double precision THEN 0.06 ELSE 0.0 END)::double precision) + (CASE WHEN (n.nr_fte < '2.5'::double precision) THEN '-0.12'::numeric ELSE 0.0 E
ND)::double precision) + (CASE WHEN (n.nr_fte >= '4.5'::double precision) THEN 0.15 ELSE 0.0 END)::double precision) + (CASE WHEN (n.pn_cvp_services = '0'::double precision) THEN '-0.05'::numeric WHEN (n.pn_cvp_services 
> '15'::double precision) THEN 0.05 ELSE '0'::numeric END)::double precision) + (n.pn_cvp_non_fashion / '40000'::double precision)), '0.01'::double precision)) * ('1'::double precision / ((GREATEST(LEAST(z.rev_wealthy, '
1.8'::double precision), '0.6'::double precision) ^ '1.5'::double precision) * exp((((x.value_num * sh.ddp) + '0.35'::double precision) + '0.1'::double precision))))) ELSE NULL::double precision END)) DESC
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 588718kB
               ->  Gather  (cost=5567.42..480211.00 rows=3489704 width=20) (actual time=37.774..913.148 rows=5019003 loops=1)
                     Workers Planned: 8
                     Workers Launched: 7
                     ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=5567.42..480211.00 rows=436213 width=20) (actual time=6.002..985.253 rows=627375 loops=8)
                           Hash Cond: (co.br_id = "*SELECT* 2".br_id)
                           ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=5503.34..476904.02 rows=436213 width=16) (actual time=5.788..902.602 rows=627375 loops=8)
                                 Hash Cond: (x.co_id = co.lo_id)
                                 ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=5352.49..432692.78 rows=436213 width=48) (actual time=5.066..816.680 rows=627375 loops=8)
                                       Hash Cond: ((z.re_id = rere.re_id) AND (n.re_id = rere.re2_id))
                                       ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=5339.56..343643.93 rows=436213 width=172) (actual time=4.980..408.478 rows=627375 loops=8)
                                             Hash Cond: ((z.zo_id = com.zo_id) AND (n.br_id = com.br_id))
                                             ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=5331.37..341345.62 rows=436213 width=172) (actual time=4.967..313.702 rows=627375 loops=8)
                                                   Hash Cond: (x.zo_id = z.zo_id)
                                                   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=14.15..331131.09 rows=435194 width=156) (actual time=0.277..169.299 rows=627375 loops=8)
                                                         ->  Parallel Hash Left Join  (cost=13.58..2718.31 rows=608 width=144) (actual time=0.239..1.337 rows=616 loops=8)
                                                               Hash Cond: ((n.shop_concept = (sh.sh_id)::double precision) AND (n.ct_id = sh.ct_id))
                                                               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on calc_nodes n  (cost=0.00..2699.38 rows=608 width=136) (actual time=0.113..0.857 rows=616 loops=8)
                                                                     Filter: ((pe_id = 405) AND (se_id = 12))
                                                                     Rows Removed by Filter: 5543
                                                               ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=13.57..13.57 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=0 loops=8)
                                                                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 40kB
                                                                     ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on calc_shopconcepts sh  (cost=4.30..13.57 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.020..0.021 rows=1 loops=4)
                                                                           Recheck Cond: ((pe_id = 405) AND (se_id = 12))
                                                                           Heap Blocks: exact=2
                                                                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_calc_shopconcepts_sepebr  (cost=0.00..4.30 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=3 loops=1)
                                                                                 Index Cond: ((pe_id = 405) AND (se_id = 12))
                                                         ->  Index Scan using rtpezocoav_ad_id_pe_id_co_id_index on rtpezocoav x  (cost=0.56..533.00 rows=715 width=16) (actual time=0.009..0.142 rows=1019 loops=4924)
                                                               Index Cond: ((ad_id = 4) AND (pe_id = 405) AND (co_id = n.co_id))
                                                   ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=5283.15..5283.15 rows=2726 width=16) (actual time=4.616..4.616 rows=2721 loops=8)
                                                         Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1280kB
                                                         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on calc_zones z  (cost=0.00..5283.15 rows=2726 width=16) (actual time=2.660..5.298 rows=3628 loops=6)
                                                               Filter: ((pe_id = 405) AND (se_id = 12))
                                                               Rows Removed by Filter: 32652
                                             ->  Hash  (cost=8.17..8.17 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=8)
                                                   Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
                                                   ->  Index Scan using rtsepezobrav_unique on rtsepezobrav com  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=8)
                                                         Index Cond: ((se_id = 12) AND (pe_id = 405) AND (ad_id = 308))
                                       ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=12.87..12.87 rows=4 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=8)
                                             Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 40kB
                                             ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on rtseperereav rere  (cost=4.39..12.87 rows=4 width=16) (actual time=0.018..0.020 rows=9 loops=1)
                                                   Recheck Cond: ((se_id = 12) AND (pe_id = 405) AND (ad_id = 306))
                                                   Heap Blocks: exact=1
                                                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on rtseperereav_unique  (cost=0.00..4.39 rows=9 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=9 loops=1)
                                                         Index Cond: ((se_id = 12) AND (pe_id = 405) AND (ad_id = 306))
                                 ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=108.71..108.71 rows=3371 width=8) (actual time=0.696..0.696 rows=1683 loops=8)
                                       Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 672kB
                                       ->  Parallel Seq Scan on rtco co  (cost=0.00..108.71 rows=3371 width=8) (actual time=0.008..2.058 rows=13464 loops=1)
                           ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=63.99..63.99 rows=7 width=12) (actual time=0.038..0.038 rows=2 loops=8)
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 40kB
                                 ->  Parallel Append  (cost=4.51..63.99 rows=7 width=12) (actual time=0.062..0.115 rows=17 loops=1)
                                       ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=38.55..38.79 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.042..0.042 rows=0 loops=1)
                                             ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=38.55..38.78 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.041..0.041 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                   Merge Cond: ((av.br_id = av_1.br_id) AND (av.br2_id = av_1.br2_id))
                                                   Join Filter: ((av_1.pe_id = rtpe.id) AND (av_1.se_id = av.se_id) AND (av_1.ad_id = av.ad_id))
                                                   ->  Sort  (cost=33.49..33.52 rows=10 width=28) (actual time=0.039..0.039 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                         Sort Key: av.br_id, av.br2_id
                                                         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                                         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.76..33.33 rows=10 width=28) (actual time=0.034..0.034 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                               ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on rtpe  (cost=4.28..8.29 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.022..0.023 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                                     Recheck Cond: (id = 405)
                                                                     Heap Blocks: exact=1
                                                                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on rtpe_id_baseline_id_idx  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                                           Index Cond: (id = 405)
                                                               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on rtsepebrbrav av  (cost=4.48..24.88 rows=16 width=28) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                     Recheck Cond: ((se_id = 12) AND (pe_id = rtpe.baseline_id) AND (ad_id = 307))
                                                                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on rtsepebrbrav_unique  (cost=0.00..4.48 rows=16 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                           Index Cond: ((se_id = 12) AND (pe_id = rtpe.baseline_id) AND (ad_id = 307))
                                                   ->  Sort  (cost=5.06..5.11 rows=18 width=20) (never executed)
                                                         Sort Key: av_1.br_id, av_1.br2_id
                                                         ->  Index Only Scan using rtsepebrbrav_unique on rtsepebrbrav av_1  (cost=0.28..4.68 rows=18 width=20) (never executed)
                                                               Index Cond: ((se_id = 12) AND (pe_id = 405) AND (ad_id = 307))
                                                               Heap Fetches: 0
                                       ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on rtsepebrbrav  (cost=4.51..25.17 rows=6 width=12) (actual time=0.061..0.069 rows=17 loops=1)
                                             Recheck Cond: ((se_id = 12) AND (pe_id = 405) AND (ad_id = 307))
                                             Heap Blocks: exact=2
                                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on rtsepebrbrav_unique  (cost=0.00..4.50 rows=18 width=0) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=17 loops=1)
                                                   Index Cond: ((se_id = 12) AND (pe_id = 405) AND (ad_id = 307))
 Planning Time: 8.603 ms
 Execution Time: 5888.474 ms
```

I guess the planner needs to gather, because it needs to evaluate *all* rows, but if I could somehow tell/steer the planner that each zo-id value is only in one worker's scope, the sorting could happen in parallel. Is this possible and how ?